# AttributeError occurs in Pyevolove

Tags: python, attributeerror, pyevolve

Recently arrived to pyevolve and I'm already very grateful for the module.

But I get an error I couldn't understand.

It is a situation such as the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\workspace\*****\src\sales.py", line 99, in <module>
ga.evolve(freq_stats=100)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyevolve\GSimpleGA.py", line 754, in evolve
self.initialize()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyevolve\GSimpleGA.py", line 593, in initialize
self.internalPop.initialize(ga_engine=self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyevolve\GPopulation.py", line 353, in initialize
gen.initialize(**args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyevolve\GenomeBase.py", line 147, in initialize
for it in self.initializator.applyFunctions(self, **args):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyevolve\FunctionSlot.py", line 180, in applyFunctions
yield f(obj, **args)
File "C:\Users\*****\Documents\workspace\*****\src\sales.py", line 61, in G1DListTSPInitializator
lst = [i for i in xrange(genome.listSize)]
AttributeError: G1DList instance has no attribute 'listSize'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

This means exactly what the error says.

G1DList have not attribute `listSize`, you have to use the method [.getListSize()](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/0_6rc1/module_g1dlist.html#G1DList.G1DList.getListSize).